# disambiguation using wikipedia

Tags: api, wikipedia

I'm trying to do some disambiguation using wikipedi's disambiguation pages. I get the list of links from the disambiguation page using the query

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&format=json&titles=stack%20overflow_(disambiguation)
```

I get the links alright, but what's the speediest way to get the text that appears next to each link? The api doesn't make it readily available. Other parts of my code are doing unavoidably time consuming work, was wondering if anybody could suggest some quick hack ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to go from "list of links" to "text next to the link" via the API. The speediest (and probably only) way is to download the page wikitext or HTML and parse that.