# extract loosly structured wikipedia text. html

Tags: html, regex, parsing, jsoup, wikipedia

Some of the html on wikipedia disambiguation pages is, shall we say, ambiguous, i.e. the links there that connect to specific persons named `Corzine` are difficult to capture using jsoup because they're not explicitly structured, nor do they live in a particular section as in [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caplan). See the page [Corzine page here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corzine).

How can I get a hold of them? Is jsoup a suitable tool for this task?

Perhaps I should use regex, but I fear doing that because I want it to be generalizable.

```
</b> may refer to:</p> 
 <ul> 
  <li><a href
```

^this here is standard, maybe I could use regex to match that?

```
<p><b>Corzine</b> may refer to:</p> 
 <ul> 
  <li><a href="/wiki/Dave_Corzine" title="Dave Corzine">Dave Corzine</a> (born 1956), basketball player</li> 
  <li><a href="/wiki/Jon_Corzine" title="Jon Corzine">Jon Corzine</a> (born 1947), former CEO of <a href="/wiki/MF_Global" title="MF Global">MF Global</a>, former Governor on New Jersey, former CEO of <a href="/wiki/Goldman_Sachs" title="Goldman Sachs">Goldman Sachs</a></li> 
 </ul> 
 <table id="setindexbox" class="metadata plainlinks dmbox dmbox-setindex" style="" role="presentation">
```

The ideal output would be

```
Dave Corzine
Jon Corzine
```

Maybe it would be possible to match the section `</b> may refer to:</p>` and also `<table id="setindexbox"` and extract all that's in between. I guess  `<table id="setindexbox"`  could be matched easily enough in jsoup, but `</b> may refer to:</p>` should be more difficule because `<b>` or `<p>` are not very distinguished.

---

I tried this:

```
      Elements table = docx.select("ul");
      Elements links = table.select("li");



    Pattern ppp = Pattern.compile("table id=\"setindexbox\" ");
    Matcher mmm = ppp.matcher(inputLine);

    Pattern pp = Pattern.compile("</b> may refer to:</p>");
    Matcher mm = pp.matcher(inputLine);
    if (mm.matches()) 
    {
    while(!mmm.matches())
      for (Element link: links) 
      {
          String url = link.attr("href");
          String text = link.text();
          System.out.println(text + ", " + url);
      }
    }
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: did you try escaping the regex character '/' with '\\/' in Pattern.compile?

Comment: yeah, but now I have a different idea, maybe like [this page](http://try.jsoup.org/~84yabFwFgJK4VojAbVK3TG-L2oA) I could use `ul a` but make sure it has `Corzine`, or whatever name i'm considering, in the title of the link? what do you think about that? maybe that would be more generalizable? but I don't know how to make it work exactly

Comment: Usually, you should use the [Wikipedia API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) instead of scraping.

Comment: @JonasCz that definetly sounds agreeable to me, but do they have the functionality that I'm looking for? I just looked into it briefly and I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859082/disambiguation-using-wikipedia), which seems to suggest that I would anyway have to do what I'm already doing. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822960/wikipedia-page-parsing-program-caught-in-endless-graph-cycle-how-to-avoid) is what I'm really trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This selector works:

```
Elements els = doc.select("p ~ ul a:eq(0)");
```

See: http://try.jsoup.org/~yPvgR0pxvA3oWQSJte4Rfm-lS2Y

That's looking for the first A element (`a:eq(0)`) in a `ul` that's a sibling of a `p`. You could also do `p:contains(corzine) ~ ul a:eq(0)` if there were other conflicts.

Or perhaps more generally: `:contains(may refer to) ~ ul a:eq(0)`

It's hard to generalize Wikipedia because it's unstructured. But IMHO it's easier to use a parser and CSS selectors than regexes, particularly over time when templates change etc.